# Registry keys associated with a certain path

Tags: registrykey

Been trying to figure out the different registry keys that can be associated with this path:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\OOBE**

I know one of them is UnattendCreatedUser, its a REG_DWORD
Does anybody know what they are or knows a link to where I can find the list of the registry keys?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this question is properly tagged. Can you explain what you are trying to do (in general)?

Comment: Hi Richard. I've been trying to deploy an image to a new hp zbook15  through the use of usb smartdeploy and landesk management suite. I had to rebuild the answer file from scratch. It appears that Microsoft has hidden some of the old registry keys in the list of keys for pxe booting. Keys that Microsoft no longer recommend using since some of them have issues but have ways around it. Found where the old keys are and solved the problems encountered. Thanks

Comment: Ah I see. This site is for _programming_ questions. I've voted to have this question migrated to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)